# How to declare a function with the same name as a property in class name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, class, oop, getter-setter

I have come across this from working with Google Firebase Authentication and Firebase Firestore. You can access the variable and the function of their classes with the same name, for example:

```
//To authenticate:
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()

//Or to access a value
firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION
```

Notice how they can use both `firebase.auth` and `firebase.auth()`. When I try to see if I can do it, it throws an error:

```
class foo {

    public bar;

    constructor() {
        this.bar = 'Bar!'; //Expecting 'Bar!' when run foo.bar()
    }

    //However, it throws an error here, as bar was already defined
    bar() {
        return 'Function bar() was called';
    }

}
```

I even tried looking into setter and getter since they also can recognize whether it was `foo.bar` or `foo.bar()` that got called, but setter does not accept a returned value.

How could I do what the Firebase Team is doing? How did they work out this magic?

Comment: Functions are an object, so you can assign them with properties and methods.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. But in the context of a function inside a class, would that be possible?

Comment: Yeah it is. Just like how hackape did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man you have to notice the equivalent to firebase style of your class should be like following, you just did it wrong.

```
class foo {

    constructor() {
        this.bar.bar = 'Bar!';
        // instead of this.bar = 'Bar!';
    }

    bar() {
        return 'Function bar() was called';
    }

}
```

However. If you must set to '.bar' as a normal value then get `.bar` back as a function, you can go with getter/setter. Just it doesn't make much sense to me.

```
class foo {

    constructor() {
        this.bar = 'Bar!';
    }

    barFunc() {
      'Function bar() was called';
    }

    get bar() {
      return this.barFunc;
    }

    set bar(value) {
      this.barValue = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be assigned additional properties.

```js
function auth () {
 return ‘banana’
}

auth.Auth = ‘wookie’;

console.log(auth()); // banana
console.log(auth.Auth); // wookie
```

Comment: Would you be able to do this for a function inside of a class? I tried setting it inside a class and it throws the same error.